# Global color variable

Tags: javascript, colors, global-variables, processing, p5.js

I have been working on an internship. The application I need to make needs to have different colors in the intersecting areas. I made a global variable of color. I am changing its values in the buttons I have created. But whenever I press the button it changes color of each intersecting area even though I have pushed it in array with its own color. How can I solve this issue

```js
let squares = [];
let overlappingsquares = []; //variable to hold squares drawn in intersecting area
let dragObject = null; // variable to hold the object being dragged

var myColour = (255);

  
function setup() {
  
  createCanvas(600, 520);
  
  button1 = createButton("Alpha");
  button2 = createButton("Bravo");
  button3 = createButton("Charlie");
  button4 = createButton("Delta");
  button5 = createButton("Echo");
  button6 = createButton("Foxtrot");
  button7 = createButton("Golf");
  button8 = createButton("Hotel");
  button9 = createButton("India");
  button10 = createButton("Juliet");

  button1.mousePressed(fun1);
  button2.mousePressed(fun2);
  button3.mousePressed(fun3);
  button4.mousePressed(fun4);
  button5.mousePressed(fun5);
  button6.mousePressed(fun6);
  button7.mousePressed(fun7);
  button8.mousePressed(fun8);
  button9.mousePressed(fun9);
  button10.mousePressed(fun10);
  
  //frameRate(1);
}

function draw() {
    background(135,206,250);

  //myColour = (255);
  // if a square is being dragged, update its position
  if (this.dragObject != null) {
    this.dragObject.position.x = mouseX;
    this.dragObject.position.y = mouseY;
  }

  //draw all squares
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    let s = squares[i];
    s.show();
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < squares.length; j++) {
      //block checking collision
      if (i != j && squares[i].collides(squares[j])) {
        squares[i].changecolor();
        
        //set intersection color
        //fill(myColour);

        //calculate parameters
        newX = Math.max(squares[i].position.x, squares[j].position.x);
        newY = Math.max(squares[i].position.y, squares[j].position.y);

        newW = Math.min(squares[i].position.x + squares[i].w, squares[j].position.x + squares[j].w) - newX;
        newH = Math.min(squares[i].position.y + squares[i].h, squares[j].position.y + squares[j].h) - newY;

        //draw rectangle
        let col = myColour
        let Osquare = new OverlappingSquares(newX, newY, newW, newH, col);
        overlappingsquares.push(Osquare);
      }
    }
  }

  
}

function mousePressed() {

  if (this.dragObject == null) {

    //ask every square if they are being "hit"
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      let s = squares[i];
      if (s.hitTest()) {
        //if so, set the drag object as this square and return
        this.dragObject = s;
        return;
      }
    }

    //no squares are hit, create a new square.
    let square = new Square(mouseX, mouseY);
    squares.push(square);
  }
}

//mouse is released, release the current dragged object if there is one
function mouseReleased() {
  this.dragObject = null;
}

class Square {
  constructor(InitialX, InitialY) {
    this.w = 60;
    this.h = 60;
    this.position = {
      x: InitialX,
      y: InitialY
    };
  }

  //basic test of mouse position against square position and if its inside the rectangle
  hitTest() {
    let x = mouseX - this.position.x;
    let y = mouseY - this.position.y;
    return (x > 0 && x < this.w) && (y > 0 && y < this.h);
  }

  show() {
    fill(50);
    rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
  collides(sqr) {
    if (this.position.x < sqr.position.x + sqr.w &&
      this.position.x + this.w > sqr.position.x &&
      this.position.y < sqr.position.y + sqr.h &&
      this.position.y + this.h > sqr.position.y) {

      return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
  changecolor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      let s = squares[i];
      s.show();

    }
    for (let i = 0; i < overlappingsquares.length; i++) {
      let s = overlappingsquares[i];
      s.show();

    }
  }
}
//Overlapping sqaures class
class OverlappingSquares {
  constructor(X, Y, W, H, C) {
    this.w = W;
    this.h = H;
    this.col = C
    this.position = {
      x: X,
      y: Y
    };
  }
  show() {
    fill(this.col)
    rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

function fun1() {
  myColour = color(0,255, 0); //green
}
function fun2() {
  myColour = color(255, 0, 0); //red
}
function fun3() {
  myColour = color(0, 0, 200); //blue
}
function fun4() {
  myColour = color(250, 0, 150); //pink
}
function fun5() {
  myColour = color(128, 0, 128); //purple
}
function fun6() {
  myColour = color(255, 255, 0); //yellow
}
function fun7() {
  myColour = color(128, 0, 0); //marroon
}
function fun8() {
  myColour = color(255, 128, 0); //orange
}
function fun9() {
  myColour = color(192, 105, 50); //brown
}  
function fun10() {
  myColour = color(255,228,196); //bisque
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: It may be that you'll need to cut this code down a little bit in order to get a good answer

Comment: Did you solve the problem or did an answer help you? You should otherwise add the solution or mark the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I went through your code and spotted this snippet

```
//draw rectangle
let col = myColour
let Osquare = new OverlappingSquares(newX, newY, newW, newH, col);
overlappingsquares.push(Osquare);
```

It's within the loop that you are calling on every single cycle. When ever you select a button, it sets the new value for '`myColour`', and within the next loop it will color all overlapping elements. You don't really tell in detail what's your goal. But some how you will need to add another color variable and identify which button intersection you want to color which way...

I think it would be better to solve this in a different way. Looping over all elements will make your program lag.
[image]

Comment: the goal is to have squares of different colors. Like suppose I made two green squares. I need the next square to be red so I would change the color by pressing the button. And yes looping was an issue. I had to make the program to draw squares on screen wherever I press. Then I could move them around and whenever they intersect the intersecting area would change the color. The way I did it has a lot of issues but I was not able to figure out another way.Still trying to solve these issues. I asked about the lagging issue in another thread but got no help.